# Original start date/time of recurring event

Tags: event

After I modify StartDateTime of an instance of recurring events series, it would be nice if I still could get information about it's original position in the series. Other systems, like Microsoft Exchange and Google Calendar provide special field OriginalStartTime for that purpose, so i was expecting something like that to be present in Salesforce as well. However I couldn't find anything similar in documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm

Can it be calculated somehow? I ended up generating a sequence of dates according to recurrence rule and matching occurrences to those dates, by finding the closest one. But this is too complex and won't work in 100% cases. So I wonder is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You goal is to capture the original value of the Event record, regardless of whether it is changed.  Natively, the Event object (nor do most) capture the initial value of a field automatically.   What you'll need to do is the following:

1. Create Custom Field on Event (might be "Activities" object) named **Intitial Start Date/Time**
2. Create a Workflow Rule on the Event Object and set it to run ***when a record is created*** and for the criteria, use something like when  **ActivityDateTime** is null --> this way it always fires the Workflow Rule
3. Add an Field Update Action to the Workflow and set the value of **Intitial Start Date/Time** equal to **Event.ActivityDateTime**.
4. Activate the Workflow rule after saving

At this point, all new events will have this value stored.   You will have to use a data loader to populate a value for all records currently in salesforce.

Now, no matter what value a user changes the ActivityDateTime, you'll always have the initial value when it was born...

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Not sure I got your point however. I'm aware of RecurrenceActivityId field, but my problem is that event can be moved to arbitrary position in the calendar. Say, I have a monthly event that occurs on 1st day of every month. If one of the occurrences (say, September 1st) was moved to September 15th, how can I get its original start?

I think maybe I was unclear with my question. I need original date/time, not just time.

Comment: Ah, much more specific!    I'll update my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still don't know if this will work for me. There might be some other requirements, like support for existing calendars/events. Considering another approaches now. I'll definitely let you know what I ended up with.
PS. Sorry, looks like my reputation is too low to upvote your answer :(